# Is there any way to access STI table through two has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When I use STI in has_many relation, I wanted to access children objects through association for super class, but I could not do it before persist.

These are sample code similar to my situation.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Child', inverse_of: :parent
  has_many :male_children, class_name: 'Children::Male'
  has_many :female_children, class_name: 'Children::Female'
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :children
end

class Children::Male < Child
end

class Children::Female < Child
end
```

When I set has_many association as association for subclasses, I could not access through association for superclass.

```
parent = Parent.new
parent.male_children << Children::Male.new
parent.female_children << Children::Female.new

parent.children # => []
```

After save and reload parent, then of course I can get children association for superclass as ActiveRecord fetch from database.

```
parent.save
parent.reolad
parent.children # => [#<Children::Male ...>, #<Children::Female ...>]
```

I can solve this by implementing instance method like this

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def children
    [male_children, female_children].flatten
  end
end
```

but I prefer association for some reason (predictability, assign params, etc).
So does anyone know how to set association definition, or is this  impossible?

Answer (score 0):

If your Male/Female children do not have different behavior then this should not be done through STI but by just using an attribute. Also this model kind of falls short when considering the fact that children usually have two parents.

When you have an attribute for the sex, you can do:

```
parent.children.where(sex: 'male')
```

But since this does not answer your question:

```
parent.male_children.build(name: 'Carl')
```

should work.

Comment: In actual code, classes are not Male/Female children. I tried to explain my trouble by parent / children relationship.


And as subclasses in actual code have different behavior, I'm glad if you suppose to Male/Female children classes have different behavior.